# Regex to get parameterized URL out of URL received

Tags: node.js

WE can an api with input say "1" and it response it can return any of below values which is again URL:

```
https://www.example.com/1
https://www.example.com/1.json
https://www.example.com/json1.json
https://www.example.com/233
```

Idea is to then create URL out of it so we can call above for other values like 1 to 10.
Expected output for above should be:

```
https://www.example.com/%d
https://www.example.com/%d.json
https://www.example.com/json%d.json
https://www.example.com/%d
```

I tried regex it worked until recent usecase broke `https://www.example.com/0001`, was exepecting `https://www.example.com/000%d` but it came as `https://www.example.com/%d` so i am thinking how can i build generic solution ?

Code i use currently:

```
function checkIfUniqueURL(url) {
    console.log(url)
    urlArr = url.split("/");
    var last = urlArr[urlArr.length - 1];
    if (last.includes(".")) {
        var first = last.split(".")[0]
        if (/^\d+$/.test(first)) {
            console.log( url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).concat(last.replace(/\d+/g, "%d")))
        }
        else {
            
            console.log(url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).concat(last.replace(/\d+/g, "%d")))
        }
    } else {
        if (/^\d+$/.test(last)) {
            console.log(url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).concat(last.replace(/\d+/g, "%d")));
        } else {
            console.log(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance ?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
function findReplaceableNumberInLastWord(url) {
  console.log('input: ' + url);
  var indexOfFirstNonZeroDigit = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
  var i = indexOfFirstNonZeroDigit;
  var indexOfLastDigit = indexOfFirstNonZeroDigit;
  for (; i < url.length; i++) {
    var c = url.charAt(i);
    if (/^[1-9]$/.test(c)) {
      break;
    } else {
      indexOfFirstNonZeroDigit++;
    }
  }
  indexOfLastDigit = indexOfFirstNonZeroDigit;
  for (; i < url.length; i++) {
    var c = url.charAt(i);
    if (/^[0-9]$/.test(c)) {
      indexOfLastDigit++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  var output = url.substr(0, indexOfFirstNonZeroDigit) + '%d' + url.substr(indexOfLastDigit);
  console.log('output: ' + output);
  return output;
}

var url = 'https://www.example.com/0001';
findReplaceableNumberInLastWord(url);
url = 'https://www.example.com/0123';
findReplaceableNumberInLastWord(url);
url = 'https://www.example.com/1023';
findReplaceableNumberInLastWord(url);
url = 'https://www.example.com/1';
findReplaceableNumberInLastWord(url);
url = 'https://www.example.com/1.json';
findReplaceableNumberInLastWord(url);
url = 'https://www.example.com/json1.json';
findReplaceableNumberInLastWord(url);
url = 'https://www.example.com/233';
findReplaceableNumberInLastWord(url);
```

Results:

```
"input: https://www.example.com/0001"
"output: https://www.example.com/000%d"
"input: https://www.example.com/0123"
"output: https://www.example.com/0%d"
"input: https://www.example.com/1023"
"output: https://www.example.com/%d"
"input: https://www.example.com/1"
"output: https://www.example.com/%d"
"input: https://www.example.com/1.json"
"output: https://www.example.com/%d.json"
"input: https://www.example.com/json1.json"
"output: https://www.example.com/json%d.json"
"input: https://www.example.com/233"
"output: https://www.example.com/%d"
```